# Error executing SQL statement for report when print jasper file

Tags: java, jasper-reports

i modify an old project and i cannot identify what is wrong with this code.using below **.jrxml** it create **.jasper** file. when i print the jasper file (using this code 
`JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,parameters,getConnection());` )  it show below error. please help me to resolve this.

---

this is top part of the **Job.jrxml** file

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"  ?>
<!-- Created with iReport - A designer for JasperReports -->
<!DOCTYPE jasperReport PUBLIC "//JasperReports//DTD Report Design//EN" "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/dtds/jasperreport.dtd">
<jasperReport
         name="Task"
         columnCount="1"
         printOrder="Vertical"
         orientation="Landscape"
         pageWidth="1275"
         pageHeight="630"
         columnWidth="1172"
         columnSpacing="0"
         leftMargin="23"
         rightMargin="80"
         topMargin="0"
         bottomMargin="0"
         whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail"
         isTitleNewPage="false"
         isSummaryNewPage="false">
    <property name="ireport.scriptlethandling" value="0" />
    <property name="ireport.encoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <import value="java.util.*" />
    <import value="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*" />
    <import value="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.*" />
    <reportFont name="Arial_Normal" isDefault="true" fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
    <reportFont name="Arial_Bold" isDefault="false" fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
    <reportFont name="Arial_Italic" isDefault="false" fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="false" isItalic="true" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Oblique" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
    <reportFont name="Courier" isDefault="false" fontName="Courier New" size="12" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Oblique" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>

    <parameter name="filter" isForPrompting="true" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="dates" isForPrompting="false" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="workFlow" isForPrompting="false" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="workFlow1" isForPrompting="false" class="java.lang.String">
            <defaultValueExpression ><![CDATA["test"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="userName" isForPrompting="false" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString><![CDATA[SELECT A.initiatedTime, A.dueTime, A.completedTime, A.taskStatus,B.jobName,
                    C.taskName,  D.firstName||' '||D.lastName AlocatedUser , E.workflowName ,B.workflowdefinition
                    FROM T_JOB_TRANSACTION A , T_JOB_DEFINITION B ,T_TASK_DEFINITION C ,T_USER D ,T_WORKFLOW_DEFINITION E
                    WHERE A.jobDefinition=B.JobID 
                    AND C.taskId=A.taskDefinition
                    AND D.userId= A.firstUser
                    AND B.workflowDefinition =E.workflowId
                    AND B.isSaved=0
                    AND c.isUsertask=1 $P!{filter} $P!{workFlow} $P!{workFlow1}
                    GROUP BY B.workflowDefinition, C.taskName, B.jobName, D.firstName||' '||D.lastName,
                    A.initiatedTime, A.dueTime, A.completedTime, A.taskStatus ,E.workflowName  
                    UNION
                    SELECT A.initiatedTime, A.dueTime, A.completedTime, A.taskStatus, B.jobName,
                    C.taskName,  D.firstName||' '||D.lastName AlocatedUser , E.workflowName ,B.workflowdefinition
                    FROM T_JOB_TRANSACTION A , T_JOB_DEFINITION B ,T_TASK_DEFINITION C ,T_USER D ,T_WORKFLOW_DEFINITION E
                    WHERE A.jobDefinition=B.JobID 
                    AND C.taskId=A.taskDefinition
                    AND D.userId= A.firstUser
                    AND B.workflowDefinition =E.workflowId
                    AND B.isSaved=0
                    AND c.isUsertask=1 $P!{userName} 
                    AND B.isInitiated=1 AND B.isCancelled=0
                    AND E.workflowId IN (SELECT A.workflowID
                                         FROM T_SUB_WORKFLOW A, T_TASK_DEFINITION B
                                         WHERE A.TASK_ID = B.taskID
                                         AND B.isSubWfInvoke = 1 $P!{workFlow} $P!{workFlow1} )
                    GROUP BY B.workflowDefinition, C.taskName, B.jobName, D.firstName||' '||D.lastName,
                    A.initiatedTime, A.dueTime, A.completedTime, A.taskStatus ,E.workflowNameorder by completedTime]]></queryString>

    <field name="initiatedTime" class="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
    <field name="dueTime" class="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
    <field name="completedTime" class="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
    <field name="taskStatus" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="jobName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="taskName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="AlocatedUser" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="workflowName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="workflowdefinition" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>

    <variable name="delay_time" class="java.lang.String" resetType="Report" calculation="Nothing">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[String.valueOf((($F{completedTime}.getTime() - $F{dueTime}.getTime())>0) ? "True":"False")]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
        <background>
            <band height="0"  isSplitAllowed="true" >
            </band>
        </background>
        <title>
            <band height="99"  isSplitAllowed="true" >
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement
                        x="5"
                        y="12"
                        width="958"
                        height="27"
                        key="staticText-2"/>
                    <box topBorder="None" topBorderColor="#000000" leftBorder="None" leftBorderColor="#000000" rightBorder="None" rightBorderColor="#000000" bottomBorder="None" bottomBorderColor="#000000"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font reportFont="Arial_Normal" size="18"/>
                    </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[NSB]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement
                        x="152"
                        y="51"
                        width="673"
                        height="21"
                        key="staticText-3"/>
                    <box topBorder="None" topBorderColor="#000000" leftBorder="None" leftBorderColor="#000000" rightBorder="None" rightBorderColor="#000000" bottomBorder="None" bottomBorderColor="#000000"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font reportFont="Arial_Normal" size="15"/>
                    </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Task Details Reports]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="false" isBlankWhenNull="false" evaluationTime="Now" hyperlinkType="None"  hyperlinkTarget="Self" >
                    <reportElement
                        x="6"
                        y="73"
                        width="957"
                        height="18"
                        key="textField"/>
                    <box topBorder="None" topBorderColor="#000000" leftBorder="None" leftBorderColor="#000000" rightBorder="None" rightBorderColor="#000000" bottomBorder="None" bottomBorderColor="#000000"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font reportFont="Arial_Normal"/>
                    </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression   class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{dates}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </title>
        <pageHeader>
```

this is the error when print report

```
 net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error executing SQL statement for report : Job
10:27:49,838 ERROR TaskReportManager:181 - net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error executing SQL statement for report : Job
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:125)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:305)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:272)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:623)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:181)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.execute_for_describe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:420)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute_maybe_describe(OracleStatement.java:896)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.execute_maybe_describe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:452)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:986)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:2888)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:2929)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:478)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:77)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:248)
    at com.affno.form.report.TaskReportManager.genReport(TaskReportManager.java:160)
    at com.affno.form.web.report.action.TaskReportAction.execute(TaskReportAction.java:412)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:484)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:525)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.affno.common.filter.SessionCheckingFilter.doFilter(SessionCheckingFilter.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

NESTED BY :
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:125)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:305)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:272)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:623)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:181)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.execute_for_describe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:420)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute_maybe_describe(OracleStatement.java:896)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.execute_maybe_describe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:452)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:986)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:2888)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:2929)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:478)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:77)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:248)
    at com.affno.form.report.TaskReportManager.genReport(TaskReportManager.java:160)
    at com.affno.form.web.report.action.TaskReportAction.execute(TaskReportAction.java:412)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:484)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:525)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.affno.common.filter.SessionCheckingFilter.doFilter(SessionCheckingFilter.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

NESTED BY :
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error executing SQL statement for report : Job
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:487)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:77)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:248)
    at com.affno.form.report.TaskReportManager.genReport(TaskReportManager.java:160)
    at com.affno.form.web.report.action.TaskReportAction.execute(TaskReportAction.java:412)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:484)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:525)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.affno.common.filter.SessionCheckingFilter.doFilter(SessionCheckingFilter.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:125)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:305)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:272)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:623)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:181)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.execute_for_describe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:420)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute_maybe_describe(OracleStatement.java:896)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.execute_maybe_describe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:452)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:986)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:2888)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:2929)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:478)
    ... 33 more
```

Comment: `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended` is syntax error in SQL. What does this do `AND c.isUsertask=1 $P!{filter} $P!{workFlow} $P!{workFlow1}`.`SQL ` donot support unary operations

Comment: thank you for your quick reply..
I have removed `$P!{filter} $P!{workFlow} $P!{workFlow1}` part and it workes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Maheswaran Ravisankar commented, you have an error in your sql: [ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_00933_sql_command_ended.htm)

The easiest way for you to debug this error is to **enable the logger** for the `JRJdbcQueryExecuter` class, the property in the `log.xml` is:

```
<logger name="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter">
    <level value="debug" />
</logger>
```

With the logger enable you will see the **actual query** that is executed and you can debug in a Oracle IDE (or post query on SO, if you can't find the error).

For more information about how to configure the log see [Jakarta Commons Logging](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/).

Comment: thank you for the quick reply and i solve it..thank you